# How to reverse the digits of an integer in PARI/GP?

Tags: reverse, digits, pari, pari-gp

As part of a mini-project I'm doing, I need a way to reverse the digits of an integer in PARI/GP (the project is mainly on palindromic numbers and digit sums).

What I'm trying to achieve in code form is `fun(13453)` giving `35431`.

For example, I've tried doing the following:

- `Vecrev(digits(13453))` gives out `[3,5,4,3,1]` but I don't know how to concatenate each consecutive element in this list.
- I don't think there is a preset function for this, as `rev`, `reverse`, or `digitrev` are not defined in PARI/GP.

Could someone show me how this can be done? Preferably, loops are undesirable as I want a simple function to put into, say, an `if` statement or a `for` loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or: `fromdigits(Vecrev(digits(13453)))`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Polrev` instead of `Vecrev`. After that, just do `subst`. Your example will be as follows:

```
> subst(Polrev(digits(13453), 'x), 'x, 10)
35431
```